# AngularJs ng show not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning AngularJs. I am notable to set the bar property correctly in the controller. Could you please let me know where I am going wrong?

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Div show Hide </h2>    
  <div ng-controller="ToggleCtrl">
    <p ng-if="foo.bar">hidden</p>
    <p ng-if="foo.bar">Shown</p>
  </div>    
</div>
```

In the controller

```
function ToggleCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.foo.bar=false
}
```

Comment: your console should show you: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'bar' of undefined` (or similar)

Comment: Yes. Thats what it shows.

Comment: Be sure that you have latest Angular version (> 1.2) in addition to initiate `foo` object

Comment: Can you please elaborate on initiation of foo object please?

Comment: This will sound harsh, though I'd suggest reading a good primer/introduction on javascript as a language before proceeding to angularjs as a framework/lib.

Comment: Thanks for your honest feedback. I am a OOO classical programmer who have dived directly into some support project containing angularJS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function ToggleCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.foo = {
    bar: false
  }
}
```